# docker-compose volume won't persist data

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am setting a nginx-gunicorn-django-**postgres** project with docker-compose.

I have a container with postgres and I want to make my data persistent. So for example when I do `docker-compose ... start/stop/up/down` I want the database to still be there. I have read that I should use volumes for this purpose as in my production.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker-compose/django/Dockerfile

    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=please_change_me
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=postgres
      - SQL_PASSWORD=postgres
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/username/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    build: ./docker-compose/nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

The problem is that whenever I do `docker-compose -f production.yaml stop` and then start again, the database is empty except for the migrations :(.
I don't know how to tackle this problem. I guess that the container maybe doesn't have permissions to write to the volume? On the other hand when I start containers for the first time everything is working well, everything is in the database and so on. It is only after `docker-compose ... stop/down` when the database is getting wiped out (again the migrations are still there).

What am I missing here?

docker-compose version: 1.24.0, 
docker version: 18.09.2

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: my problem was that I was flushing db in entrypoint script... I copied it from some tutorial and didn't notice it for a long time

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give this more visibility but full credit to @marke in the comment. The problem I was having was I was flushing the db in my entrypoint. In django, I was running `python manage.py flush` which resets the db.